# java Authenticate an EWS application by using OAuth

Tags: exchangewebservices

I have an java app which supports Basic Authentication，Microsoft is disabling the Basic Authentication option across all Office 365 Tenants on October 1.

In this case, how do I achieve Authenticate an EWS application by using OAuth using java? Is there a proper documentation with Java code available?Thanks a lots.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what libraries your using in Java but regardless of the language your using the first thing you will need is an application registration and you need to decide on the type of oAuth authentication flow you are going to use which depends on the type of application you have see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth as a starter